# button enable and disable when user clicked on checkbox

Tags: jquery, checkbox

here is my fiddle link, i dont know how to perform checkbox check events to enable disable buttons.

```
 http://jsfiddle.net/ojtca35b/2/
```

Here i disabled all the checkbox.  and i want to do the following operations.  If i click on group selector, it must enable " delete, email and pdf buttons" .  if the user click on any single row, it must enable all the buttons.

please help me on this, it may be an existing question, but i couldnt find right solution to solve it.

Comment: Publish your code here.

Comment: you can get my code in fiddle .  and its above in the jquery.

Comment: i dont know  , what i  asked wrong to vote it down.  please dont drop it down.  here i couldnt post my code here.  thats the reason i showed it on fiddle.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ojtca35b/6/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ojtca35b/7/

Comment: If you will not publish your code here, after some time jsfiddle code can disappear. And your question and answer can be useless.

Comment: Thank you learner.  your answered it exactly close to my doubt .  thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `.on('change', func)`:

```
var editInvoice = $('.edit-invoice');
var deleteInvoice = $('.delete-invoice');
var emailInvoice = $('.email-invoice');
var pdfInvoice = $('.pdf-invoice');

$('.group-checkable').on('change', function () {
        if (!this.checked) {
            editInvoice.prop('disabled', false);
            deleteInvoice.prop('disabled', true);
            emailInvoice.prop('disabled', true);
            pdfInvoice.prop('disabled', true);
        }
        else {
            editInvoice.prop('disabled', true);
            deleteInvoice.prop('disabled', false);
            emailInvoice.prop('disabled', false);
            pdfInvoice.prop('disabled', false);
        }
});

$('.checkboxes').on('change', function () {        
    if (this.checked) {
        editInvoice.prop('disabled', false);
        deleteInvoice.prop('disabled', false);
        emailInvoice.prop('disabled', false);
        pdfInvoice.prop('disabled', false);
    }
    else {
        editInvoice.prop('disabled', true);
        deleteInvoice.prop('disabled', true);
        emailInvoice.prop('disabled', true);
        pdfInvoice.prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

**[jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ojtca35b/8/)**

Comment: Thank you Mohamad shiralizadeh. its helped me a lot,  i was wondering such a perfect answers.